# Netty getting An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline on TextWebsocketEncoder

Tags: java, exception, netty

I try to do simple web socket decode and then encode but I'm getting this exception when it pass the TextWebsocketDecoder  handler:

```
io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext exceptionCaught
WARNING: An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:101)
    at io.netty.buffer.DefaultByteBufHolder.release(DefaultByteBufHolder.java:73)
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:59)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:112)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketServerProtocolHandler$1.channelRead(WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.java:147)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:263)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:304)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What I have is simple Initializer which work find until TextWebsocketEncoder:

```
public class ServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<Channel> {
    private final ChannelGroup group;

    public GameServerInitializer(ChannelGroup group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    @Override
    protected void initChannel(Channel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(64 * 1024));
        pipeline.addLast(new ChunkedWriteHandler());
        pipeline.addLast(new HttpRequestHandler("/ws"));
        pipeline.addLast(new WebSocketServerProtocolHandler("/ws"));
        pipeline.addLast(new TextWebSocketFrameHandler(group));
        pipeline.addLast("textWebsocketDecoder",new TextWebsocketDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("textWebsocketEncoder",new TextWebsocketEncoder());
    }
}
```

TextWebSocketFrameHandler

```
public class TextWebSocketFrameHandler  extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<TextWebSocketFrame>{
     private final ChannelGroup group;

        public TextWebSocketFrameHandler(ChannelGroup group) {
            this.group = group;
        }

        @Override
        public void userEventTriggered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object evt) throws Exception {
            if (evt == WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.ServerHandshakeStateEvent.HANDSHAKE_COMPLETE) {

                ctx.pipeline().remove(HttpRequestHandler.class);

                group.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame("Client " + ctx.channel() + " joined"));

                group.add(ctx.channel());

            } else {
                super.userEventTriggered(ctx, evt);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, TextWebSocketFrame msg) throws Exception {
             ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
            //group.writeAndFlush(msg.retain());
        }
}
```

and this are the TextWebsocketDecoder and TextWebsocketEncoder :

TextWebsocketDecoder :

```
public class TextWebsocketDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<TextWebSocketFrame>
{

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, TextWebSocketFrame frame, List<Object> out) throws Exception
    {
        String json = frame.text(); 
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        int type = jsonObject.getInt("type");
        JSONArray msgJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("msg");
        String user = msgJsonArray.getString(0);
        String pass = msgJsonArray.getString(1);
        String connectionkey = msgJsonArray.getString(2);
        int timestamp = jsonObject.getInt("timestamp");

        JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject();
        responseJson.put("type",Config.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
        responseJson.put("connectionkey",connectionkey);

        out.add(responseJson); // After This im getting the exception !!!
    }
}
```

TextWebsocketEncoder

```
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageEncoder;
import io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.TextWebSocketFrame;

public class TextWebsocketEncoder extends MessageToMessageEncoder<JSONObject>
{

    @Override
    protected void encode(ChannelHandlerContext arg0, JSONObject arg1, List<Object> out) throws Exception {
        String json = arg1.toString();
        out.add(new TextWebSocketFrame(json));          
    } 

}
```

Comment: Can you show your TextWebSocketFrameHandler?

Comment: The warning generally means that an exception ocurred and you are not catching it. The default handler behaviour is to pass it to the next handler. You have to override `exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause)` somewhere.

Comment: @ferrybig i fixed and update the question adding TextWebSocketFrameHandler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The exception

Inside your TextWebSocketFrameHandler, you are calling `ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);`, this passes the message up 1 chain, however `MessageToMessageDecoder` isn't prepared to deal with this. To explain this problem I need to explain how the MessageToMessageDecoder works.

`MessageToMessageDecoder` works by catching every message from the upstream and passing them to your custom code, your custom code handles the work, and the mtmd handles the closing of the resource you passed in.

Since you are passing the reference to the other side, you are effectively closing the WebSocketFrame multiple times, causing bugs. MessageToMessageDecoder even warns you for this in the [javadoc](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/MessageToMessageDecoder.html).

To solve the problem, we follow the instruction in the manual and make our channelRead the following:

```
@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, TextWebSocketFrame msg) throws Exception {
     msg.retain(); // ferrybig: fixed bug http://stackoverflow.com/q/34634750/1542723
     ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
     //group.writeAndFlush(msg.retain());
}
```

### The not sending back problem

Inside your comments, you stated the code doesn't send anything back. This is expected as your pipeline only consumes data and passes it up the chain. To fix this, it would require some rework at your pipeline.

1. We need to swap the order of the json-webframe decoder and encoder:

   ```
   pipeline.addLast("textWebsocketDecoder",new TextWebsocketEncoder());
   pipeline.addLast("textWebsocketEncoder",new TextWebsocketDecoder());
   ```

   This is because your Decoder is generating the output that would be send back ↑ the chain of handlers, this output won't be seen by the encoder if the decoder was above that. (Your decoder shouldn't be called a decoder following the netty naming)
2. We need to change your decoder to send the generated data actually back ↑ the chain instead of ↓ into the non-existing void.

   To make these changes, we going to let the `TextWebSocketDecoder` extend `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` instead of `MessageToMessageDecoder<TextWebSocketFrame>` since we are handling messages instead of passing them to a other handler.

   We are changing the signature of the decode method to `channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg)`, and add some boilerplate code:

   ```
   public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) /* throws Exception */
       TextWebSocketFrame frame = (TextWebSocketFrame) msg;
       try {
           /* Remaining code, follow the steps further of see end result */
       } finally {
           frame.release();
       }
   }
   ```
3. We adapt our code to pass the result up the pipeline instead of down:

   ```
   public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) /* throws Exception */
       TextWebSocketFrame frame = (TextWebSocketFrame) msg;
       try {

           String json = frame.text(); 
           JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
           int type = jsonObject.getInt("type");
           JSONArray msgJsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("msg");
           String user = msgJsonArray.getString(0);
           String pass = msgJsonArray.getString(1);
           String connectionkey = msgJsonArray.getString(2);
           int timestamp = jsonObject.getInt("timestamp");

           JSONObject responseJson = new JSONObject();
           responseJson.put("type",Config.LOGIN_SUCCESS);
           responseJson.put("connectionkey",connectionkey);

           ctx.writeAndFlush(responseJson)
       } finally {
           frame.release();
       }
   }
   ```

Notice that you may be tempted to remove our previous code from the exception, but doing this will trigger undefined behavior when ran under the async nature of netty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , now i have no execution but it is not continuing to 
TextWebsocketEncoder handler .. any idea why ?

Comment: @user63898 Updated the answer

Comment: So you are saying that the TextWebsocketEncoder and the TextWebsocketDecoder are not needed ? if i understand you right ?

Comment: very strange the  ctx.write(responseJson) never get back to the client 
i also tryed  ctx.channel().write(responseJson); 
it is invoked but never cached by the onmessageonmessage in the browser

Comment: ok found the problem it should be :  ctx.channel().writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame(responseJson.toString()));
but how come i dont need the encoder / decoder ?

Comment: You need the encoder, decoder and other things on the pipeline, the flow of the data in the pipeline goes as follows: `(Raw bytes) ↘ HttpServerCodec ↘ HttpObjectAggregator ↘ HttpRequestHandler ↘ WebSocketServerProtocolHandler ↘ TextWebSocketFrameHandler ↘ **TextWebsocketDecoder** ↗ TextWebsocketEncoder ↗ WebSocketServerProtocolHandler ↗ HttpRequestHandler ↗ ChunkedWriteHandler ↗ HttpServerCodec ↗ (Raw bytes)
`, where ↘ means `channelRead` and ↗ means `ctx.writeAndFlush`. Hope you understand

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer much appreciated . 
the problem that i dont understand is that i manged to implemet all the logic inside the TextWebSocketFrameHandler class , the broswe gets the massages fine . and the encoder / decoder never called .
its working BUT , im sure im dong something wrong here that will hort me latter and i do want to understand why the encoder never called

Answer (score 1):

You use `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` which auto-releases catched data according to documentation.

So, when you call `ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);` to pass msg to others handlers on pipeline, there is a problem besauce msg will be released.

To fix this, you can use `ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter` or you can stop auto-releasing process of `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` by calling the proper constructor, or you can call `ReferenceCountUtil.retain(msg);` before firing upper on pipeline.

See documentation of SimpleChannelInboundHandler here:
http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/SimpleChannelInboundHandler.html

and read about Reference counted objects here (new concept of netty 4):
http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html

Comment: The retain worked but it is stoped in the TextWebsocketDecoder 
i want to send it back to the client using TextWebsocketEncoder

Comment: To send data to the client, call `ctx.writeAndFlush()` method. But, it sends downstream on the pipeline, so probably the encoder should be before your handler on pipeline